# Visual Studio Regex: Replace all #include statements using backslash with forward slash

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013

In my C++ code, I have a mixed use of backslash and forward slash for my `#include` statements. I would like to standardize on using forward slash.

Keep in mind that the includes could look like any of the following:

```
#include "file.h"
#include <file.h>
#include "dir\file.h"
#include <dir\file.h>
#include <dir1\dir2\file.h>
#include "..\file.h"
```

etc.

Does anyone know of a good way to use Visual Studio 2013's "Find and Replace" regex functionality to do this?

Comment: I think it will be better for you to use a text editor like *NotePad++* that supports regex, And please give us your expected result ;).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find: `(#include.*?)\\`

Replace with: `$1/`

The problem is that when you have a requirement (having `#include.*` in your case) but multiple matches (as there can be any number of backslashes in the filepath), it's not easy (and sometimes impossible) to write a general-purpose solution.

However, to keep it simple, you can use the mentioned regex and replace to find the first backslash in all the lines, replace it with forward slash. Then you can repeat it as many times as you need until you have no matches found (the amount of times is equal to the highest depth of filepath).

Comment: Thanks, this worked very well! You are right, it had to do a 2nd and sometimes 3rd pass on some of these lines, depending on how many '\' characters there were, but this single line updated all my code. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for adding a comment to an 4 years old question. However i had same problem today because i wanted to compile some windows code using winegcc on linux. I found out that it was very easy using the strg-shift-h _replace in files dialog_ instead of the simple strg-h _replace dialog_ from within visual studio, because latter is closed after each run and former stays open for the next run.